# Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string while running docker exec command

Tags: bash, docker, sh

I've been dealing with this for about 3 days. I tried most of the combinations of double and single quotes, looked at most of the stackoverflow questions and answers and still no luck :( Below is the simplified version of my problem.

```sh
> line="008256042a1b sh -c \"mysqldump databasename\""
> echo $line
008256042a1b sh -c "mysqldump databasename"
> docker exec $line
databasename": 1: databasename": Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

Comment: You need to know on which container you want to run that instruction...it should be something like `docker run busybox bin/sh -c $line`

Comment: @Hackerman this states exactly which container to run the command in, and it uses `exec` to do it without creating a new container but using the environment to pass the command. The OP is trying to run tasks in an existing container and has provided a [mcve]. I don't see how your comment is relevant.

Comment: This is [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: @Hackerman, using `$line` that way is buggy for the reasons described in the BashFAQ #50 link above.

Comment: @SE it was just a comment, not an answer...just like CD comment...comments should give hints about how to get to the actual answer...if you didn't get it that way, it's your problem...SMH

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you tried to put a command in $line, it's like you want to run:

```
sh -c \"mysqldump Database\"
Database": 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

This should work :

```
line=(008256042a1b sh -c "mysqldump databasename")
echo "${line[@]}"
docker exec "${line[@]}"
```

`"mysqldump databasename"` is a single string.

`\"mysqldump databasename\"` is actually two strings.

`"${line[@]}"` allows the proper expansion of array items.

Comment: For more details, I recommend reading http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer Run this, you'll see it's working `docker run --name sleepy ubuntu sleep infinity & line=(sleepy sh -c "echo mysqldump databasename"); sleep 1; docker exec "${line[@]}"'

Comment: @Philippe Yeah, that works, thanks. I'd misread (and mistyped) your solution as `$()` (subshell) rather than just `()` (array). But, I suppose the clue is in the `@`. Perhaps you could add a word or two explaining the solution a little more (the array bit anyway).

Comment: I up voted because it's a working solution. But, I'm using the app and it's a little buggy and is giving me a strange error so who knows :)

Answer (score -1):

Can you substitude the "docker exec" also ?
Then it simply becomes

`line="008256042a1b sh -c \"mysqldump databasename\""`
OR
`line="008256042a1b sh -c 'mysqldump databasename'"`
OR even
`line="008256042a1b mysqldump databasename"`

THEN
`eval "docker exec ${line}"`

edit: this can only be used when you trust what's in $line. Other wise, it is a security issue as mentionned in comments.

Comment: This _works_, but it's not at all a good idea. [BashFAQ #48](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) applies, which is why the approaches described in [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) are better.

Comment: Yes, I understand that it is vulnerable to injection, but I assumed the input is trusted (which I hope it is since it would allow running anything on any container !). If it is, it's way simpler ...

Comment: Often an array will be assembled by code that's piecing together trusted and untrusted bits, so you can have the first field be trusted, the second field be untrusted, etc; but for evaling a string, anything untrusted at all and it can run arbitrary code on not just containers but the host too.